# What does this mean in the docs for random.shuffle?

Tags: python, random

http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle

> `random.shuffle(x[, random])`
>
> Shuffle the sequence *x* in place. The optional argument *random* is a 0-argument function returning a random float in [0.0, 1.0); by
>   default, this is the function `random()`.
>
> Note that for even rather small `len(x)`, the total number of permutations of *x* is larger than the period of most random number
>   generators; this implies that most permutations of a long sequence can
>   never be generated.

Can someone please explain to me what the last sentence means?

It sounds like maybe there's a limit to the size of list that you can or should use `shuffle` on?

Comment: What it says to me is that you can shuffle, but there's no way you can generate every permutation by _shuffling_, just a subset of them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means that for longer lists, the random number generator will start repeating itself, so that the number of different possible 'shuffles' for a given list is not going to be the number of permutations of the list.

For a list of length *N*, there are *N!* (*N* factorial) possible ways to permute the list order, but if the random generator starts repeating itself after fewer than N! iterations, then the `random.shuffle()` function will not be able to produce all *N!* permutations for that list.

It'll still be able to shuffle the list, but even if you shuffled the list an infinite number of times, it will not produce all *possible* orderings for such a list.

The default `random.random()` function uses the Mersenne Twister algorithm, which has a period of 2**19937-1.  That means that you'd need a list of length 2081 before you will see this behaviour occur.

Comment: Mathematically that can be explained more or less like this: `Let P be the set of all possible permutations of list L {p1,p2,...pn} and S the number of possible permutations generated by shuffle() {s1,s2,...sm}. Then S is a proper subset of P for every long enough L`.

Answer (score 1):

If x is a sequence of 10 items, then there'll be a possible 3,628,800 possible orders in which the list could be arranged.. but most random number generators (being not truly random) will will cycle through a finite number of "random" numbers - this finite number might be less than the 3,628,800 possible permutations of your original 10 elements so some of the possible permutations will never come up as a result of shuffling.

It doesn't mean there'll be a limit to the size of the sequence accepted by the shuffle function.